# Turning a dataset into a nested tuple

Tags: python, nested, tuples

I have a .txt dataset that I need to convert into a nested tuple. Here's part of the dataset:

```
Morocco, Rabat, 0.75 million|Algeria: 1000 KM,  Tunisia: 400 KM, Western Sahara: 50 KM|North Atlantic Ocean
Western Sahara, , 1.51 million|Morocco: 50 KM, Mauritania: 350 KM|North Atlantic Ocean
Senegal, Dakar, 0.5 million|Mauritania: 50 KM, Guinea Bissau: 30 KM, Guinea: 30 KM, Mali: 30 KM|North Atlantic Ocean, South Atlantic Ocean
...
```

The tuple needs to have the following layout:

```
(countryname, capital, population, ((neighbor1, distance1), (neighbor2, distance2),...etc..), (waterbody1,...etc.))
```

I'm most of the way there, except that the nested neighbor and water body tuples only have the first of multiple values, like this:

```
('Senegal', 'Dakar', 0.5, ['Mauritania', 50 KM], ['North Atlantic Ocean'])
```

But it should look like this:

```
('Senegal', 'Dakar', 0.5, (('Mauritania', 50), ('Guinea Bissau', 30), ('Guinea', 30), ('Mali', 30)), ('North Atlantic Ocean', 'South Atlantic Ocean'))
```

Here's my code:

```
def readData(fileHandle):
    
    ds = ()

    for line in fileHandle:
        row = line.split('|')

        countryname, capital, population = row[0].split(", ")
        population = float(population.strip(" million"))

        ngbr_list = row[1].split(', ')
        for neighbor in ngbr_list:
            ## change neighbor from 'nbrX:distX KM' to 'nbrx', float(distx)
            n_name, distance = neighbor.split(': ')
            distance = float(distance.strip(' KM')) 
           
        water_body_list = row[2].split(', ')

        ds = ds + ((countryname, capital, population, (n_name, distance), (water_body_list)),)
    return ds
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing neighbour name and distance. That is resulting into only one n_name and distance. try to store all the n_name and distance in a list and then add the list to dataset.

Here is the code. This may help you.

```py
def readData(fileHandle):
    
    ds = ()

    for line in fileHandle:
        row = line.split('|')
        countryname, capital, population = row[0].split(", ")
        population = float(population.strip(" million"))

        neighbor_distance_list = []
        ngbr_list = row[1].split(', ')
        for neighbor in ngbr_list:
            ## change neighbor from 'nbrX:distX KM' to 'nbrx', float(distx)
            n_name, distance = neighbor.split(': ')
            distance = float(distance.strip(' KM'))
            neighbor_distance_list.append((n_name, distance))
           
        water_body_list = row[2].split(', ')

        ds = ds + ((countryname, capital, population, tuple(neighbor_distance_list), tuple(water_body_list)),)
    return ds
```

Output is:

`(('Morocco', 'Rabat', 0.75, (('Algeria', 1000.0), ('Tunisia', 400.0), ('Western Sahara', 50.0)), ('North Atlantic Ocean Western Sahara', '', '1.51 million')), ('Senegal', 'Dakar', 0.5, (('Mauritania', 50.0), ('Guinea Bissau', 30.0), ('Guinea', 30.0), ('Mali', 30.0)), ('North Atlantic Ocean', 'South Atlantic Ocean')))`

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it had something to do with the way I was constructing the neighbor list. It also never occurred to me to use the tuple() function nested inside the ds = line. I tried to do the same thing by doubling the parentheses around the neighbor and water body lists, but it didn't turn them from lists into subtuples.

Answer (score 0):

`str.strip(letters)` does not remove a suffix from a string. It removes any combination of the letters from the end of a string.  That is, `population.strip('ilmno ')` is the same as `population.strip(' million')`.
Both would remove `' million'` from the end of `population`, but they would also turn `'ten million'` into `te`.